# Can't insert into database using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to insert a group of people into a database table. I can select from the database without problems but when I try to enter I get

```
Cannot add an entity with a key that is already in use
```

I know what this means but why is it happening. I have increment on the tables id. Here's my code.

```
    public static List<Person> GetPeople(DataContext db)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>();            
            Table<Person> People = db.GetTable<Person>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Person pers = new Person();
                pers.PersFirstName = "Wesley " + i;                
                //pers.PersId is the primary key that I want to auto-increment and not have to set it here
                people.Add(pers);            
            }
            People.InsertAllOnSubmit(people);
            People.Context.SubmitChanges();

            IQueryable<Person> query =
            from person in People
            select person;


            return people;
        }
```

The problem happens at the line

```
People.InsertAllOnSubmit(people);
```

Is there some special way i have to set up auto-increment with Linq?

Comment: You'll have to set that the database increments the identity value. Have you set that `PersonId` is the primary key?

Comment: Yeah I have already done this

Comment: Have you set the pk before you generated the mapping? If not recreate the mapping file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your dbml designer, click on the column that's the primary key and ensure that the following properties have these values:

```
Auto Generated Value: True
Auto-Sync: OnInsert
Primary Key: True
```

Since you're not using the dbml designer, you can accomplish it with parameters on a Column attribute for your field property (which will be in addition to the other parameters you will likely have already).

```
[Column(AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
```

Comment: Good stuff. I Didn't create the linq to sql classes, i created my own normal class. Thanks again

Comment: @WesleySkeen - I've updated with the non-DBML way of specifying those properties.